# How to update multiple Vue 3 components when Pinia array changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I can't get multiple components accessing the same store respond to updates, until I mess with a dom element to trigger new render.

In my Pinia store, I have an array, and an update method:

```js
    let MyArray: IMyItem[] = [
    { id: 1,
      name: "First Item",
    }, ....
    let SelectedItem = MyArray[0]
    const AddItem = ( n: string, ) => {       
        MyArray.push({ id: createId(), name: n, });
        };

    return { MyArray, SelectedItem, AddItem  }
```

In one Vue component, I have text inputs and a button to call the store's method:

```js
    function handle() {store.AddItem(name.value));
```

In another Vue component, on the same parent, I use a for loop to display allow for selecting an item:

```html
    <div v-for="item in store.MyArray">
          <input type="radio"...
```

No changes with these efforts:

```js
    const { MyArray } = storeToRefs(store);
    const myArray = reactive(store.MyArray);
    // also watching from both components...
    watch(store.MyArray, (n, o) => console.dir(n));
    // also... lots of other stuff.
    const myArray = reactive(store.MyArray);
    watch(myArray, (n, o) => console.dir(n));
```

I also experimented with `<form @submit.prevent="handle">` triggering `nextTick` by adding a string return to the store's method.

I assume the reason clicking around makes it work is because I'm changing the the store's `SelectedItem`, and its reactivity calls for re-rendering, as it is `v-model` for a label.

The docs say Array.push should be doing it's job... it just isn't bound the same way when used in `v-for`.

What's needed to trigger the dom update? Thanks!

Comment: In the component that should update, define a computed property that just returns the store's value and use the computed property for rendering your template.

Comment: could you show ur pinia store

Comment: The top code block is the store.  It exposes 3 things: MyArray, SelectedItem, and AddItem function.

Comment: `let MyArray: IMyItem[] = [` - it's not reactive, this is a mistake. `const myArray = reactive(store.MyArray)` - doesn't make sense because store.MyArray is already supposed to be reactive at this point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As comments pointed out, the main issue is your store state is not declared with the Reactivity API, so state changes would not trigger watchers and would not cause a re-render.

The solution is to declare `MyArray` as a [`reactive`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive) and `SelectedItem` as a [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref):

```js
// store.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import type { IMyItem } from './types'
import { createId } from './utils'
               
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'

export const useItemStore = defineStore('item', () => {
                   
  let MyArray = reactive([{ id: createId(), name: 'First Item' }] as IMyItem[])
                     
  let SelectedItem = ref(MyArray[0])
  const AddItem = (n: string) => {
    MyArray.push({ id: createId(), name: n })
  }

  return { MyArray, SelectedItem, AddItem }
})
```

If using `storeToRefs()`, make sure to set the `ref`'s `.value` property when updating the `SelectedItem`:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
const store = useItemStore()
const { SelectedItem, MyArray } = storeToRefs(store)
const selectItem = (id) => {
                 
  SelectedItem.value = MyArray.value.find((item) => item.id === id)
}
```

But in this case, it's simpler to use the props off the `store` directly:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
const store = useItemStore()
const selectItem = (id) => {
  store.SelectedItem = store.MyArray.find((item) => item.id === id)
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-pinia-store-state-reactivity?file=src%2Fstore%2Findex.ts)